# PHP Login fail - return with error

Tags: php, html, database, authentication

I'm working on a login system and I want, I case the user entered wrong username & password to return him to the login page with an error ("Wrong username or password" for example)

At the moment I'm using 2 files:
file number 1 - html - the login form that post the username & password to file number 2
file number 2 - php - checks the username & password, in case they match, redirect to the next page
else, displays an error message in page number 2

I want it to display the error message in page number 1.

I'll appreciate your help

Guy Dor

Comment: You should not write your own login-system because probably it is going to be VERY INSECURE. You should use something like openid, facebook connect or Twitter Single sign-in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the error message and set it as a session variable. This type of session message is called "flash message".

Check out a similar question [Help a Beginner with a PHP based Login System](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642494/help-a-beginner-with-a-php-based-login-system)

The example on that question contains a way to implement session based flash message.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the common way to do this is to have the login form reprint on the php page after you determine the login was wrong.  Otherwise page 1 would have to be a php as well so that you could do the logic to display the warning after page 2 redirects back to it.

Comment: basically you would have something like this below.  It will echo out your login form for the user to attempt another login with.

if(!$fail)
{
  echo "<form action='page2.php' method='post'><input type='text' name='username'><input type='text' name='password'><input type='submit' value='loginButton'></form>";
}